# ¿Cómo puedo pasar de tener una lista de solo números enteros a una impresión de los mismos en sin comas y como str?

Tags: python

Tengo esta lista:

```
[1,4,6,8,9] // Como números enteros y no como str
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me quede de resultado esto?:

```
"1 4 6 8 9"
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Si lo único que quieres es imprimirlo? en ese caso puedes hacer print(' '.join(map(str, lista)))

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 5):

Con el método join() de String puedes hacerlo:

```
lista = [1,4,6,8,9]
cadena = " ".join(map(str, lista))
```

Referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp

Comment: Este código te daría error, puesto que la lista contiene enteros y join funciona con cadenas, tendrías que transformarlas previamente.

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace tienes razón, se me olvidó hacer el casteo a string. Ya lo he corregido, gracias por el aviso!

Answer (score 5):

Y por dar una opción más, menos conocida, puedes usar el operador asterisco, o *splat* (desempaquetado de iterables) así:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4]
print(*lista)
```

El operador `*` delante de un iterable lo "desempaqueta" y lo convierte en una serie separada de argumentos. `print()` recibirá entonces los números de la lista como argumentos separados, y no como un solo argumento de tipo lista. Es decir, `print(*lista)` es lo mismo en este caso que `print(1,2,3,4)`.

Ya que, de forma natural, `print()` admite cualquier número de argumentos y los imprime separados por espacios, tendrías el resultado deseado. Si quisieras separarlos de otra forma, puedes usar el argumento `sep` de print. Por ejemplo, `print(*lista, sep=", ")` para que salgan separados por coma y espacio.

Como ves esta solución es la más compacta de las propuestas, pero hace uso del desempaquetado de iterables, que es un operador poco conocido, por lo que quizás podría considerarse menos legible que otras opciones.

Answer (score 2):

Combinando strip y replace puedes conseguir lo que quieres. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = str(a).strip('[]').replace(',', '')
print(b)
```